# add more options in records per page dropdown using datatable jquery

Tags: datatables, jquery-pagination

I've been using the datatable jquery (http://datatables.net/ ) plugin.

Everything is working fine, but now I want to be able to select more than the default options of records per page, by default I can choose 10 , 25 , 50 , 100. I want to add 15 and 30 to this list.

How can I do that, I searched on internet but could't find any answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `pageLength` and `lengthMenu` for setting the default view, like this:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
        "pageLength": 15,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 15, 25, 35, 50, 100, -1], [10, 15, 25, 35, 50, 100, "All"]]
    });
```

old api

```
  $('#example').dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "aLengthMenu": [[10, 15, 25, 35, 50, 100, -1], [10, 15, 25, 35, 50, 100, "All"]]
    });
```

Second array will hold the values for that will be displayed in the drop down menu

Read more: [DataTables example - Page length options](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/length_menu.html)

Comment: thanks Daniel. I've been looking the documentation but there is to many things that I lost myself browsing throught it.